# Unfortunately, project has stopped! Ошибка при открытии нового Активити

Tags: android, activity

При открытии эта ошибка выскакивает.

### Unfortunately, project has stopped!

Вот полный Манифест:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ContentActivity">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Вот сам код:

```
imageView8.setOnClickListener(onClicker);
}

View.OnClickListener onClicker = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContentActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Вот ошибка:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: com.project, PID: 6875
>                                                             android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.project/com.project.ContentActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
>                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
>                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
>                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
>                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
>                                                                 at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
>                                                                 at com.project.StartActivity$1.onClick(StartActivity.java:34)
>                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: <activity android:name=".ContentActivity"/> Активити в манифесте не прописан

Comment: Если прописать, то при установке 2 ярлыка создаются на эмуляторе

Comment: @Omuradil, чтоб не было двух ярлыков во второй активити не надо прописывать `<intent-filter>`

Comment: @Omuradil, и когда приложение падает, обычно оно падает с какой-то подробной инфой в логах.

Comment: Вот полный манифест! Теперь с .ContentActivity - ошибка

Comment: Unfortunately, project has stopped! (Не повезло, проект остановлен!) - система пишет это при возникновении ЛЮБОЙ ошибки, которая привела к падению приложения. Она не является хоть каким то признаком того, что случилось, а лишь констатацией факта, что это произошло. Не стоит указывать это сообщение, как причину ваших проблем. Реальная причина падения содержится в стэктрейсе при падении приложения, его и надо приложить.

Comment: Именно из за этих проблем. Так как в других местах нет проблем, на 100%!

Comment: Данное сообщение значит примерно то же, что и "Я заболел" и потом после этого очень информативного диагноза требовать, чтобы вас немедленно выличили. Оно не проблема, из-за коорой что то случилось, а уведомление, что это произошло.

Comment: Я еще раз говорю что тут у меня проблемы. Но не могу понять что неправильно написал.

Comment: Я вам могу посочувствовать с вашими проблемами, но не обладаю экстрасенсорными способностями, чтобы сканировать ваши ошибки оттуда, где я сейчас нахожусь. Прикладывайте СТЕКТРЕЙС ОШИБКИ и код, который их вызывает. Одного вашего уверения в том, что у вас проблемы недостаточно для решения проблем.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос по ошибке с `Activity has no default constructor`, а этот вопрос верните в вид, на который вы получили ответ.

Comment: Не меняйте вопрос, на который вы уже получили ответ. Если ситуация и ошибка изменились — задайте новый вопрос. Этот я вернул в прежнее состояние.

Answer (score 1):

`"have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"`  попробуйте указать полный путь к активити

```
<activity android:name="com.packagename.ContentActivity">
    </activity>
```

И уберите

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

из вашего `SearchActivity`

Comment: Убрал) А полный путь тоже не помогла.com.project.ContentActivity has no default constructor.

Comment: @Omuradil, теперь, судя по всему, у вас проблема в том, что у вас в активити есть конструктор, хотя его там быть вовсе и не должно.

Comment: Вопрос уже так изменен, что ответ не является ответом .. по хорошему нужно делать откат на первоначальный вопрос и пусть новый вопрос задает по новой проблеме. Маекните кто-нибудь модераторам на этот комментарий что ли .

Comment: @pavlofff, тревогнул)

Comment: @pavlofff: залочил.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: спасибо.